# Flash Drive completely unrecognizable yet I can access files on it

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive, usb-drive

This is the strangest behavior I have ever seen with a storage device. When I connect my USB flash drive, it automatically opens the directory `/media/albert/Linux Mint 17.3 MATE 64-bit` and I can see the files in that directory. I can also unmount the drive from the file browser. Nevertheless, I cannot add new files even as root. However, the strangest part is that when I run Gparted, the drive is not present anywhere. Moreover, `sudo fdisk -l` also reveals no trace of the drive? I am completely lost as to what could I do to format the drive.

Background to the problem: I had Linux Mint on the drive and I wanted to format it. When I opened Gparted, I was given an error message having to do with EFI and requiring me to create a new partition table. I created a new msdos partition table, and when the operation completed, Gparted no longer could see the drive. I have subsequently tried testing this on other machines and on Windows and the result is the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the output of dmesg after I connect the drive:

```
[ 2398.903776] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd    
[ 2398.924870] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000    
[ 2398.924880] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3    
[ 2398.924885] usb 4-4: Product: Silicon-Power64G    
[ 2398.924890] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: UFD 3.0    
[ 2398.924894] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 459y458964365756k5    
[ 2398.926160] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected    
[ 2398.926723] scsi14 : usb-storage 4-4:1.0    
[ 2400.078005] scsi 14:0:0:0: Direct-Access     UFD 3.0  Silicon-Power64G 1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6    
[ 2400.078959] sd 14:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0    
[ 2400.079566] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] 125829120 512-byte logical blocks: (64.4 GB/60.0 GiB)    
[ 2400.080048] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off    
[ 2400.080056] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00    
[ 2400.080537] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 2400.087612]  sdb:    
[ 2400.089881] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk    
[ 2400.259653] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3    
[ 2400.260897] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
```

Comment: Are you using Linux Mint as the OS?

Comment: If it doesn't show up in `fdisk -l`, what about `parted -l`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't see any partitions because the media is not partitioned. Before USB was invented the convention was that harddisk were partitioned and flopydisks were not partitioned.

When USB storage came along it wasn't clear which of the two should be the case for USB, so it ended up being necessary to support both.

The reason you cannot write any files to the device appears to be that it is using the ISO 9660 file system which is read only (as it was designed for CD ROM media).

You should be able to confirm this by typing:

```
grep sdb /proc/mounts
```

And I expect you will find a line starting with

```
/dev/sdb /media/albert/Linux\040Mint\04017.3\040MATE\04064-bit iso9660
```

The lack of a partition number after `sdb` indicates that the file system is on the raw media rather than a partition, and `iso9660` indicates while file system is being used.

You can also try this command to see which devices are partitioned and which are not:

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

Answer (score 0):

I never managed to get Linux to recognized my USB drive in its damaged state. Then I switched to Windows and tried using the tool provided by Silicon-Power.That also did not work. Ultimately, I was actually able to solve the problem by going to Disk Management within windows, and there the drive was present as unallocated, and I was able to format it.

I still don't understand, however, why did this happen. More responses to this would still be helpful for those who come here in the future.